# Using variable and strings to create name with posixpath

Tags: python, path, pathlib

I want to create a path with python pathlib using a variable.

This is of course incorrect due to mixing of string and posixpath:

```
from pathlib import Path
stringvariable='aname'

Path(Path.cwd() / 'firstpartofname_' +stringvariable+ '.csv')
```

I know I could do it with os, or in two lines like this:

```
filename='firstpartofname_' + stringvariable + '.csv'
Path(Path.cwd() / filename)
```

but I want to learn how to use it directly with Path.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add parentheses to force the `+` to happen before the `/`.

```py
new = Path.cwd() / ('firstpartofname_' + stringvariable + '.csv')
```

Comment: :-) I cannot have you sleepless nights, so I fixed the spelling :-D